# Retrieve and display data from Array Document

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, nosql-aggregation

This is my example document :

```
{
  _id:1,
  name:Dennis,
  tasks:[{
     task:'Drawing',
     dateFinished: Date()
  },{
     task:'Paint',
     dateFinished: Date()
  }]
}
```

I want to get the data from my document and display it like this, sorted by DATE :

```
_id:1, task:'Drawing', dateFinished:<here is the date >
_id:1, task:'Paint', dateFinished:<here is the date >
```

How can I display this data sorted by DATE ? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below query.

```
  db.Example.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$tasks"
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "tasks.dateFinished": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "task": "$tasks.task",
      "dateFinished": "$tasks.dateFinished"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "tasks": 0
    }
  }
])
```

Here is [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vRm4lfDEUJz) for you.